# Wie muss man "halten" auf französisch übersetzen, wenn es mit "es" benutzt wird bzw. "Er hält es mehr mit seiner Mutter"

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context, french

Ich kann schon die Bedeutung von "er ist mehr seiner Mutter zugetan" begreifen aber habe wirklich Schwierigkeiten die passende Übersetzung auf Französisch zu finden insbesondere wenn ich versuche ein Wort zu finden das von "tenir" nicht zu entfernt ist.

Darf ich schreiben: "Ca colle mieux avec sa mère"?
Es ist eben mehr kompliziert mit "Man erzählt sich, dass sie es mit ihrem Chef hält". Darf ich schreiben: "On dit qu'elle en pince pour son chef"? Ist diese Übersetzung zu umgänglich?

Mir fällt es aber praktisch unmöglich mit: "Er hält es stets mit der Bequemlichkeit". Darf ich schreiben: "Sa paresse lui colle à la peau"?

Comment: DeepL's take on this: [Il est plus proche de sa mère.](https://www.deepl.com/translator#de/fr/Er%20h%C3%A4lt%20es%20eben%20mehr%20mit%20seiner%20Mutter.)

Comment: Die deutsche Bedeutung scheint ja klar zu sein... die Frage ist demzufolge über die richtige Formulierung in einer anderen Sprache, nämlich französisch und damit für diese Community leider nicht geeignet

Comment: Vielleicht passt die Frage nicht in diese Community, aber einen Grund für ein Downvote sehe ich nicht.

Answer (score 2):

Mon français est très limité, mais j'essaye de expliquer l'expression allemande ;) (Mein Französisch ist sehr begrenzt, aber ich versuche, den deutschen Ausdruck zu erklären)

Der Ausdruck "es mit etwas halten" oder "es mit jemandem halten" bedeutet grundsätzlich, dass man eine Ansicht oder eine Haltung zu einem Thema teilt.

> Ich halte es mit Cicero. Der wusste nämlich schon: 'Die Welt ist ein Irrenhaus'.
> (Ad familiares IX, XXII: [Stultorum plena sunt omnia](https://de.wikiquote.org/wiki/Cicero))

> Wie hältst Du es mit dem Stromsparen?

Es gibt also eine Ähnlichkeit zur Formulierungen wie

> Was hältst Du von Stefans Vorschlag?

oder

> Wie ist Deine Haltung zu dem Vertragsentwurf?

Im übertragenen Sinne kann man "es mit etwas halten" oder "es mit jemandem halten" auch verwenden mit einer Bedeutung wie "etwas bevorzugen" oder "jemanden bevorzugen". Es liegt nahe zu vermuten, dass diese Variante bei

> Er hält es mehr mit seiner Mutter (als mit seinem Vater).

gemeint ist, aber genau sagen kann man es ohne Kontext nicht.